# Proving the union of set with set of its limit points is closed

Tags: general-topology, limits, analysis

Here is my attempt:

Consider the set $A'$ of all limit points of $A$. Then clearly, any limit point of $A$ must also be a limit point of $A \cup A'$.

Now consider any limit points of $A \cup A'$, say x. Now, $\forall U_x \in \tau$ with $x \in U_x$,

$\bigcup U_x \cap ((A \cup A')-\{x\}) \neq \varnothing \\$

$ \rightarrow (\bigcup U_x \cap A-\{x\}) \cup (\bigcup U_x \cap A-\{x\}) \neq \varnothing$

Since the union of these two is nonempty then at most one can be empty. If the first is nonempty then x is a limit point of A. Now if the second is nonempty all this tells us that x is a limit point of $A'$ the set of limit points of $A$.

Is there a way to prove it this way?

Comment: You have a misplaced parenthesis and a missing $'$ in your final equation

Comment: One of the open sets in $\tau$ is the entire space, which I'll call $X$. Since it is the entire space, it includes $x$. Thus $\bigcup U_x = X$. And $$\bigcup U_x \cap ((A \cup A')-\{x\}) = (A \cup A')-\{x\}\\\bigcup U_x \cap A-\{x\} =  A-\{x\} \\ \bigcup U_x \cap A'-\{x\} =  A'-\{x\}$$ Either of the last two being non-empty does not imply $x$ is a limit point. It only means that $A$ or $A'$ consists of more than just $x$. The condition for being a limit point is $\forall U_x, U_x \cap A - \{x\} \ne \emptyset$, not$\bigcup U_x \cap A -\{x\} = \emptyset$.